# Regex matching php

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to replace a given url with another one in php using preg_replace, with the following code:

```
$patt = '#(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?((?:[^\.]+)\.)?example\.com#i';
preg_replace($patt,"http://$1anotherwebsite.com",$somehtml);
```

I'm having two issues however:
I would like `$1` to be blank if the subdomain is `www.`, but it seems that `((?:[^\.]+)\.)?` matches `www.` and not `(?:www\.)?` as expected. This seems to be a php specific issue.

In the case of this [example](http://rubular.com/r/gyPP0X8SPn), the second match contains part of the first string. Is there anyway I could limit this to only match between `<` and `>`? I tried using `(<.*)` and `(.*>)`, but nothing matched.

EDIT: Here are some sample inputs / outputs:

`http://static.example.com/assets/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js?1384234134 ->  http://static.anotherwebsite.com/assets/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js?1384234134`

`http://www.example.com -> http://anotherwebsite.com`

`example.com -> http://anotherwebsite.com`

`https://example.com/index.php -> http://anotherwebsite.com/index.php`

The links are coded in html, so restricting the match to be between `<` and `>` would work I believe.

Comment: To make your question clear provide your sample inputs and expected matches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$html = preg_replace('~(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?([^\.\s]+\.)?example\.com~i',
                       'http://$1anotherdomain.com', $html);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
This doesn't seem to match `http://www.example.com` though.

Comment: @rthur: Sorry, but you didn't mention that your *several* urls are *inside an html document*. I will edit my answer to make it work, however a DOM method seems to be more appropriate for what you are trying to do.

Comment: I managed to modify your answer to get it to work, here's what I ended up with: `~\"(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?([^\.\s]+\.)?'.preg_quote($value).'([^\"]+)?\"~i`. I hadn't realized all the HTML URLs where wrapped in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

For parsing URL and applying rule PHP's built-in [**`parse_url`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) is much better suited to handle complexity of all sort of URL stricture.

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/foo/bar';
$arr = parse_url($url);
$output = 'http://anotherwebsite.com';
// apply path only if www isn't there
if (stripos($arr['host'], 'www.') !== 0) {
   $path = isset($arr['path']) ? $arr['path'] : '';
   $output = 'http://anotherwebsite.com' . $path;
}

echo $output;
```

**Using DOM:**

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html); // loads your html
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodelist = $xpath->query("//a");
for($i=0; $i < $nodelist->length; $i++) {
    $node = $nodelist->item($i);
    $url = $img->getAttribute('href');
    $arr = parse_url($url);
    $output = 'http://anotherwebsite.com';
    // apply path only if www isn't there
    if (stripos($arr['host'], 'www.') !== 0) {
       $path = isset($arr['path']) ? $arr['path'] : '';
       $output = 'http://anotherwebsite.com' . $path;
    }
    $node->setAttribute('href', $url);
}
// save HTML back
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I need to replace all the URL's in a HTML document though, how would I do that with your solution?

Comment: You can get all the URLs of a HTML document using DOM parser and then apply this code on top of that.

Comment: From what I understand the DOM parser would get all the URLs in <a> tags, but it wouldn't necessarily get the ones used to define scripts or css files.

Comment: Check the updates. For `css/js` you need to just a different `$xpath->query(...)`